# How C++ expands multiple parameters packs simultaneously,

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++-templates

Having following functions `f0`, `f1`, `f2` in C++14 code, which accepts arbitrary number of fixed-length arrays:

```
#include <functional>
template<typename... TS, size_t N> void f0( TS(&& ... args)[N] ) {}
template<typename T, size_t... NS> void f1( T(&& ... args)[NS] )  {}
template<typename... TS, size_t... NS> void f2( TS(&& ... args)[NS] )  {}
 
int main(){
    f0({1,2}, {3.0,4.0}, {true, false});
    f1({1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6});
    f2({1,2,3}, {4.0,5.0}, {true});
    return 0;
}
```

Function `f0` accepts arrays with different types and fixed array length. Function `f1` accepts arrays with fixed type and different array lengths. It's clear how this works: C++ compiler deduces variable-length parameter pack in immediate context of template function instantiation, which is expanded in `(&& ... args)` expression.

Function `f2` accepts arrays with different types and different array lengths, which produces two variable-length parameter packs, however there is only one ellipsis operator in pack expansion `(&& ... args)`, but code compiles and works well.

So question is: what is general rule for expanding multiple parameter packs within single ellipsis operator? Obviously, at a minimum, they must be the same length, but what are the other requirements? Is there a precise definition that the n-th element of the first parameter packing should expand along with the n-th element of the second parameter packing?

Also, following code with explicit template argument provision does not compile: `f2<int,float,bool,3,2,1>({1,2,3},{4.0f,5.0f},{true});`. It would be interesting to know the reasons for this behaviour.

Comment: "Is there a precise definition that the n-th element of the first parameter packing should expand along with the n-th element of the second parameter packing" -- yes, that's the precise definition, itself, as is. The answer to your question is to, basically, repeat the question.

Comment: ... Just swapping the first two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in C++ Standard section [[temp.variadic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.variadic). Basically, it's what you described: when a pack expansion expands more than one pack, all those packs must have the same number of elements. And the expansion in most cases forms a list where the nth element in the resulting list uses the nth element of each expanded pack.

More exactly, paragraph 5 defines

> A *pack expansion* consists of a *pattern* and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). The form of the pattern depends on the context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in the following contexts:
>
> - In a function parameter pack; the pattern is the *parameter-declaration* without the ellipsis.
> - ...

In your example, each function template declares a function parameter pack named `args`. The patterns are `TS(&& args)[N]`, `T(&& args)[NS]`, and `TS(&& args)[NS]`.

Paragraph 7 (after clarifying which packs are expanded by which pack expansions that when one pack expansion appears inside another) has the requirement

> All of the packs expanded by a pack expansion shall have the same number of arguments specified.

And paragraph 8:

> The instantiation of a pack expansion that is neither a `sizeof...` expression nor a *fold-expression* produces a list of elements E<sub>1</sub>, E<sub>2</sub>, ..., E<sub>*N*</sub>, where *N* is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. Each E<sub>*i*</sub> is generated by instantiating the pattern and replacing each pack expansion parameter with its *i*<sup>th</sup> element.

So yes, for the instantiation of `f3` where `TS` is deduced as `int`, `double`, `bool` and `NS` is deduced as `3`, `2`, `1`, the pack expansion becomes a function parameter list with types `int(&&)[3], double(&&)[2], bool(&&)[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

All packs appearing as part of one pack expansion (`...`) must have exactly the same length. Otherwise substitution fails (which depending on context is a hard error or SFINAE). (see [[temp.variadic]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.variadic#7.sentence-4))

All packs are expanded so that the i-th expanded element of the pack expansion uses the i-th element of each pack. For the detailed expansion rule see [[temp.variadic]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.variadic#8).

(Links are to the post-C++20 draft of the standard, but the same applies to C++14.)

Answer (score 0):

A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments (non-types, types, or templates). A function parameter pack is a function parameter that accepts zero or more function arguments.

A template with at least one parameter pack is called a variadic template.

**Visit[1]:** https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

**Visit[2]:** [Multiple expansions of multiple parameter packs in the same expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382002/multiple-expansions-of-multiple-parameter-packs-in-the-same-expression)

**Visit[3]:** https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=only-variadic-templates-c11

I hope this help you.

Comment: While this is true, I don't see how this answers the question in any way at all.

Comment: Okay, thank you for comment. I am new here and still learning how can I answer like this question. So after this comment I gonna improve my answers and be careful  when answering in any question. And thank you again. @cigien